# Как настроить встроенный дебагер в PhpStorm10?

Tags: php, phpstorm, отладка, xdebug

Как настроить связку storm+xdebug я знаю, а как настраивается в 10 версии встроенный что то не пойму.

Comment: Что значит встроенный дебаггер? Можно поподробнее? О_о

Comment: Ну может я что то неправильно понял но разработчики роде как анонсировали встроенныцй дебагер в 10 версии точнее улучшенную консоль [ссылка](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/)

Comment: Имеешь в виду отображение данных сразу как вот тут на верхней картинке: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/img/10/interactive-debug2.png  ??

Comment: Ну да типа что то этого

Comment: Так его не надо настраивать. Он уже работает, Надо только поставить точку останова в коде и начать дебажить :))